# jQuery iterating over HTML Dom element string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

```
var htmlDoc = $(data);
htmlDoc.each($("link"), function(index, value){
           console.log(value);
});
```

How can I iterate over htmlDoc object's elements? Not the main document's, but that htmlDoc's.

Comment: Like `htmlDoc.find("link").each(...)`?

Comment: I guess. Like this?  htmlDoc.find("link").each(function(index, value){
                                        console.log($(value));
                                })

Comment: Yes, pretty much. You can also use `function () { console.log($(this)); }`